# apirtc connectedUsersListUpdateHandler issue

Tags: angularjs, asp-classic

I use ApiRTC for both our ASP classic web site and AngularJS app.

In  both cases the library is https://cloud.apizee.com/apiRTC/apiRTC-latest.min.js

In both cases when the user logs in, the list of connected users they see is correct whether they are logged into the ASP web site or the App.

If a user logs in or out of the web site, all other web users immediately see the revised correct list.  This is the case no matter if they are on Mac Chrome or PC Chrome.

The app on the other hand does NOT receive an update.  And if an app user logs in our out, the web site users do not get updated.  But if the web site user logs out and in, then they once again have an accurate online user list.

So for some reason the App does not detect any changes to other app or web users.  And web users detect changes between each other but not app users.  Also after the initial login the there is nothing hitting the console indicating any activity with apirtc (i.e. no connectuser updates).

following is debug from the connect in the app

```
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.364Z] [INFO] apiRTC : apiRTC initialization, version is :3.15.9
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.366Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Android detected forcing protocol to https
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.368Z] [INFO] apiRTC : Setting ccsServer
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.371Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : bandwidthTestServer is not defined
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.373Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : userData :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.377Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : apiRTC JS Librairies already loaded
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.379Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : initParameters have changed, need to reload session connection
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.381Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : initParameters.userData :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.385Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : initParameters.apiCCId :-2147483632
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.387Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : userData is defined :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.390Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : apiCC.session.userData :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.393Z] [INFO] apiRTC : reOpenChannel
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.395Z] [INFO] apiRTC : ApiCC_Channel::initialize()
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.397Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : openChannel channelId :-2147483632
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.399Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : session.apiKey :(removed from this copy)
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.401Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : session.sessionId :f7181460-c7e8-11e7-a3ab-253da1ba6a6e
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.403Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : CCSserver used : ccs5.apizee.com:443
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.406Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Defined userData : 
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.409Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : stringUserData.length :58
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.411Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Defined presenceGroup : -2147483645,-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.413Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : stringPresenceGroup.length :25
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.415Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Defined subscribeToPresenceGroup : -2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.417Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : stringsubscribeToPresenceGroup.length :13
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.419Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : requestOptions on connect : &userData=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Demo%20Staff%22%2C%22company%22%3A-2147483645%2C%22dpt%22%3A%22Supply%22%7D&presenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%2C-2147483645%5D&subscribeToPresenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%5D
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.421Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : session.ccsServer :ccs5.apizee.com:443
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.422Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Port is also set in ccsServer definition
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.424Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : res[0] : ccs5.apizee.com
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.427Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : res[1] : 443
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.429Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Android detected forcing protocol to https
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.432Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : use new ccs, socket url is : https://ccs5.apizee.com:443/?channelId=-2147483632&apiKey=d682fd039f4f7d066b62624aae2e4235&apiVersion=3.15.9&sessionId=f7181460-c7e8-11e7-a3ab-253da1ba6a6e&siteId=-2147483645&userData=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Demo%20Staff%22%2C%22company%22%3A-2147483645%2C%22dpt%22%3A%22Supply%22%7D&presenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%2C-2147483645%5D&subscribeToPresenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%5D
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.442Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Nickname is defined :Demo Staff
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:57.444Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : photoURL is not defined
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.637Z] [INFO] apiRTC : Channel opened
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.643Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : this.channelId :-2147483632
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.650Z] [INFO] apiRTC : ApiCCSession onChannelOpened
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.657Z] [INFO] apiRTC : createSessionReadyEvent
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
sessionready
controllers.js (469,17)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.667Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Adding listener on type :userMediaSuccess
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.672Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Adding listener on type :incomingCall
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.678Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Adding listener on type :userMediaError
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.683Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Adding listener on type :remoteStreamAdded
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.688Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Adding listener on type :hangup
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.693Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Adding listener on type :connectedUsersListUpdate
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.698Z] [INFO] apiRTC : createWebRTCClient
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.703Z] [INFO] apiRTC : apiCC.ApiCCWebRTCClient
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.709Z] [INFO] apiRTC : WebRTC_Adapter
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.713Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : adapter.browserDetails.browser :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.719Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : adapter.browserDetails.version :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.726Z] [INFO] apiRTC : SDPManager
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.732Z] [INFO] apiRTC : ApiCCMCUClient creation
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.737Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : default this.pc_config configuration
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.741Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : record feature is activated
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.746Z] [INFO] apiRTC : RecordManager creation
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.752Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : localVideo Div Name is not correct : INCORRECT_DIV_NAME_LOCALVIDEO
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.757Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : miniVideo Div Name is not correct : INCORRECT_DIV_NAME_MINIVIDEO
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.761Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : remoteVideo Div Name is not correct : INCORRECT_DIV_NAME_REMOTEVIDEO
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.765Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : status Div Name is not correct : INCORRECT_DIV_NAME_STATUS
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.769Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : command Div Name is not correct : INCORRECT_DIV_NAME_COMMAND
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.773Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Status Div Null
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.778Z] [INFO] apiRTC : getMediaDevices
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.782Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : enumerateDevices() is supported.
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.790Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : onChannelMessage S->C: {"type":"updatePresence","group":-2147483645,"connectedUsersList":["-2147483643","-2147483633","-2147483632"],"connectedUsersListWithStatus":[{"userId":"-2147483643","callState":"no_Call","userData":{"name":"Efficient Apps Admin","company":"-2147483645","dpt":"","webRtcCompliant":"true","dtlsCompliant":"true","osName":"Windows","browser":"Chrome","version":"61.0.3163.100","apiRTCVersion":"3.15.9","id":"-2147483643","audioDevicePresent":"true","videoDevicePresent":"true"}},{"userId":"-2147483633","callState":"no_Call","userData":{"name":"Demo Manager","company":"-2147483645","dpt":"EVS","webRtcCompliant":"true","dtlsCompliant":"true","osName":"Mac OS","browser":"Chrome","version":"61.0.3163.100","apiRTCVersion":"3.15.9","id":"-2147483633","audioDevicePresent":"true","videoDevicePresent":"true"}},{"userId":"-2147483632","callState":"no_Call","userData":{"name":"Demo Staff","company":"-2147483645","dpt":"Supply","id":"-2147483632"}}],"state":"online"}
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.793Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : updatePresence
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.797Z] [INFO] apiRTC : updatePresence[object Object]
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.801Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : updatePresence for group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.804Z] [INFO] apiRTC : manageConnectedUsersList
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.807Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : state :online
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.811Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.814Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : state : online
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.817Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : connectedUsersListWithStatus  :0
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.821Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : this.connectedUsersList is empty
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.824Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : this.connectedUsersList[0].group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
connectedUsersListUpdateHandler
controllers.js (441,17)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.831Z] [INFO] apiRTC : getConnectedUserIdsList, group :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.835Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : getConnectedUserIdsList : complete users list
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.841Z] [INFO] apiRTC : displayConnectedUsersList
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.846Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483643 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.847Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483633 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.850Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483632 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.857Z] [INFO] apiRTC : MediaDevices detection in webRTCClient
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.858Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Audio device present
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.860Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Video device present
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.863Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Audio output present
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.865Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Audio device detected :true
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.868Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Video device detected :true
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.870Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : apiCC.session.apiCCWebRTCClient.webRTCClient.gum_config:
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.873Z] [INFO] apiRTC : setUserData in session
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.875Z] [INFO] apiRTC : mergeJSON
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.878Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91634)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.882Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : this.userData :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.885Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : actualUserData :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.888Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : this.updateUserDataToBeDone :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91791)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.890Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : C->S: {"type":"setUserData","userData":{"audioDevicePresent":true,"videoDevicePresent":true}}
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.899Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : socket.io 1.X : socket.io.opts.query:channelId=-2147483632&apiKey=d682fd039f4f7d066b62624aae2e4235&apiVersion=3.15.9&sessionId=f7181460-c7e8-11e7-a3ab-253da1ba6a6e&siteId=-2147483645&userData=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Demo%20Staff%22%2C%22company%22%3A-2147483645%2C%22dpt%22%3A%22Supply%22%7D&presenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%2C-2147483645%5D&subscribeToPresenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%5D
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.901Z] [INFO] apiRTC : updatingQuery
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.903Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : socket.io 1.X : after update : socket.io.opts.query:channelId=-2147483632&apiKey=d682fd039f4f7d066b62624aae2e4235&apiVersion=3.15.9&sessionId=f7181460-c7e8-11e7-a3ab-253da1ba6a6e&siteId=-2147483645&userData=%7B%22name%22%3A%22Demo%20Staff%22%2C%22company%22%3A-2147483645%2C%22dpt%22%3A%22Supply%22%2C%22audioDevicePresent%22%3Atrue%2C%22videoDevicePresent%22%3Atrue%7D&presenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%2C-2147483645%5D&subscribeToPresenceGroup=%5B-2147483645%5D
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
connectedUsersListUpdateHandler
controllers.js (441,17)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.907Z] [INFO] apiRTC : getConnectedUserIdsList, group :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:58.909Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : getConnectedUserIdsList : complete users list
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.465Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : onChannelMessage S->C: {"type":"updatePresence","group":-2147483645,"connectedUsersList":["-2147483632"],"connectedUsersListWithStatus":[{"userId":"-2147483632","callState":"no_Call","userData":{"name":"Demo Staff","company":"-2147483645","dpt":"Supply","id":"-2147483632","audioDevicePresent":"true","videoDevicePresent":"true"}}],"state":"online"}
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.471Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : updatePresence
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.479Z] [INFO] apiRTC : updatePresence[object Object]
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.483Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : updatePresence for group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.488Z] [INFO] apiRTC : manageConnectedUsersList
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.494Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : state :online
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.499Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.503Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : state : online
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.508Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : connectedUsersListWithStatus  :0
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.513Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : userData is updated
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
connectedUsersListUpdateHandler
controllers.js (441,17)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.522Z] [INFO] apiRTC : getConnectedUserIdsList, group :
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.527Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : getConnectedUserIdsList : complete users list
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.535Z] [INFO] apiRTC : displayConnectedUsersList
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.539Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483643 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.544Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483633 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.549Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483632 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.673Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : onChannelMessage S->C: {"type":"updatePresence","group":-2147483645,"connectedUsersList":["-2147483632"],"connectedUsersListWithStatus":[{"userId":"-2147483632","callState":"no_Call","userData":{"name":"Demo Staff","company":"-2147483645","dpt":"Supply","id":"-2147483632","audioDevicePresent":"true","videoDevicePresent":"true"}}],"state":"online"}
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.696Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : updatePresence
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.701Z] [INFO] apiRTC : updatePresence[object Object]
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.706Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : updatePresence for group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.712Z] [INFO] apiRTC : manageConnectedUsersList
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.717Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : state :online
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.721Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.725Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : state : online
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.730Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : connectedUsersListWithStatus  :0
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.734Z] [INFO] apiRTC : displayConnectedUsersList
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.738Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483643 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.742Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483633 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:40:59.746Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : User :-2147483632 on group :-2147483645
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
```

Following is debug from the disconnect in the app.

```
[2017-11-12T20:36:55.377Z] [INFO] apiRTC : setCookie
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:36:55.384Z] [INFO] apiRTC : setCookie
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:36:55.386Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : Disconnecting from Server
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:36:55.389Z] [INFO] apiRTC : onChannelDisconnect
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
[2017-11-12T20:36:55.391Z] [DEBUG] apiRTC : date :Sun Nov 12 2017 15:36:55 GMT-0500 (EST)
apiRTC-latest.min.debug.js (51,91493)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The apiCCId was an integer.  Converting it to a string (toString()) fixed everything.  So odd how it sort of worked with that error..